# Discord.py - In embed.fields.1.value: This field is required error

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm  getting a `In embed.fields.1.value: This field is required` error when I try to embed something but the error never happened before

The code I'm trying to use is a user info command:

```py
 @commands.command()
 async def uinfo(self, ctx, member:discord.Member=None):
  member=ctx.author if not member else member
  roles=[role for role in member.roles]

  embed=discord.Embed(colour=discord.Colour.gold())

  embed.set_author(name=f"User Info ~ {member}")
  embed.add_field(name="Their ID: ", value=member.id, inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="Joined server at: ", value=member.joined_at.strftime("%a, %#d %B %Y, %I:%M %p UTC"), inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="Joined discord at: ", value=member.created_at.strftime("%a, %#d %B %Y, %I:%M %p UTC"), inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name=f"Their roles: ", value=" ".join([role.mention for role in roles]), inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="Highest role: ", value=member.top_role.mention, inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="Is Discord bot?", value=member.bot, inline=False)
  embed.set_footer(text='Multi-Galaxy | Coded by Dr Jakaboii#2019')

  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 BAD REQUEST (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In embed.fields.1.value: This field is required
In embed.fields.2.value: This field is required
```

Comment: Side note: It can't have anything to do with the amount of letters because my server info command works fine and it has more letters in it

Comment: I can't reproduce this, the command works fine for me.  You could try printing the values while you're building the embed, to see if any of them are not as you expect.

Comment: ok, ill try that

Comment: also, im on discord.py version 1.2.3 & python version is 3.6.8

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I found out what's wrong, it's: ```embed.add_field(name="Joined server at: ", value=member.joined_at.strftime("%a, %#d %B %Y, %I:%M %p UTC"), inline=False)``` & ```embed.add_field(name="Joined discord at: ", value=member.created_at.strftime("%a, %#d %B %Y, %I:%M %p UTC"), inline=False)``` any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: im not 100% sure on how to use time, if I can i'd like it to be GMT+1 but, as i said, im not sure how

Comment: What exactly is the problem with those lines?  What do those `strftime` calls produce?

Comment: i used a different format and it worked, sorry for some of the waste of time

Answer (score 2):

Use value='\u200' it will keep the value empty